# How do I get the text of an QLineEdit into a method?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm still not able to understand how to properly connect Qt_pushButton or Qt_LineEdit to methods. I would be so glad to get a explanation which even I do truly understand...

I've put together a pretty basic UI with Qt Designer. It contains a lineEdit called "lineEditTest" which I can indeed change by typing

```
self.lineEditTest.setText("changed Text")
```

However, I'm totally stuck with getting the text which the user entered back into my program. I would like to automatically submit the entered text into my function which sets a var to this value and returns it into my UI class. QLineEdit's signal editingFinished sounds perfect for that I guess? But it won't pass the text which the user entered into my function.

QLineEdit does have a property called "text" right? So it seems logical to me that I just have to pass another arg - apart from self - to my function called text.

My code does look like this but it obviously won't work at all:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)

        self.lineEditTest.setText("test")
        self.lineEditTest.editingFinished.connect(self.changeText(text))
        self.show()

    def changeText(self):
        currentText = text
        print (currentText)
        return currentText

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

This will just crash with:

```
NameError: name 'text' is not defined`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the OP doesn't understand the logic of the signals and slots (I recommend you check [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)). The signals are objects that emit information, and the slots are functions (generally *callable*) that are connected to the signals to receive that information. And the information transmitted by the signal depends on each case, for example if you check [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) of [`editingFinished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished) signal:

> **void QLineEdit::editingFinished()**
>  This signal is emitted when the
> Return or Enter key is pressed or the line edit loses focus. Note that
> if there is a validator() or inputMask() set on the line edit and
> enter/return is pressed, the editingFinished() signal will only be
> emitted if the input follows the inputMask() and the validator()
> returns QValidator::Acceptable.

That signal does not send any information so do not expect to receive any information except knowing that the edition has ended by the user. So how can I get the text? Well, through the [`text()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop) method of QLineEdit:

```py
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test.ui", self)

        self.lineEditTest.setText("test")
        self.lineEditTest.editingFinished.connect(self.changeText)
        self.show()

    def changeText(self):
        text = self.lineEditTest.text()
        print(text)
```

And how to do if the signal sends information? Then the slot (the function) that this connected will have as arguments to that information, for example if you use the [`textChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textChanged) signal that is emitted every time the text of the QLineEdit is changed, it should be as follows:

```py
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("test.ui", self)

        self.lineEditTest.setText("test")
        self.lineEditTest.textChanged.connect(self.changeText)
        self.show()

    def changeText(self, text):
        print(text)
        # or
        # text = self.lineEditTest.text()
        # print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're binding your callback isn't correct. When you bind a callback (and this is true for other frameworks, not just for binding callbacks in PyQt), you want to bind the function which should be triggered when a certain event occurs. That's not what you're doing - you're explicitly invoking the callback `self.changeText(text)` (note: the parentheses invoke the function). So, you're invoking (calling) the function, evaluating it and placing the return value in `...editingFinished.connect()`.

Don't explicitly invoke the function. Just pass the function's name. This makes sense if you think about it: we're passing a callable object to `connect` - this is the function which should be called at a later point in time, when the `editingFinished` event occurs.

You also don't need to pass `lineEditTest`'s text into the callback, since you can just get whatever text is in the widget via `self.lineEditTest.text()` from inside the callback.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        from PyQt5 import uic

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)

        self.lineEditTest.setPlaceholderText("Type something...")
        self.lineEditTest.editingFinished.connect(self.on_line_edit_finished_editing)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_line_edit_finished_editing(self):
        text = self.lineEditTest.text()
        print(f"You finished editing, and you entered {text}")


def main():
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    application = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()

    window.show()

    return application.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```